# LiveData changed but not observed : JetPack Compose

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata, android-jetpack-compose

I've organized my code in MVVM: I've a LoginScreen that send to LoginViewModel the onClickEvent when user click LoginButton.
When the event occurs, viewModel set the state variable (MutableStateFlow Type) and the action variable (SingleLiveEvent type).
Login screen observe this changes and print a String when state change, or navigate to home when action is "NavigateToHome".

This is the problem: everything seems work, when user click login button, action is set, LoginScreen observe action and navigate to home but when from home, user go back to login page (via system back button) and redo the login, state and action are set by viewModel but not observed by login screen.

This is my LoginScreen:

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
    viewModel: LoginViewModel,
navController: NavController
) {
    observeStates(viewModel)
    observeActions(viewModel, navController)
    loginScreenUI(viewModel)
}

@Composable
fun observeActions(viewModel: LoginViewModel,navController: NavController) {
    val action: LoginScreenAction by viewModel.actions.observeAsState(initial = LoginScreenAction.Default)
    when(action){
        LoginScreenAction.NavigateToHome -> {
            println("get ACTION: NavigateToHome")
            navController.navigate("home")
        }
        LoginScreenAction.Default -> {
            println("get ACTION: Default")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun observeStates(viewModel: LoginViewModel) {
    //val state: LoginScreenState by viewModel.states.observeAsState(initial = LoginScreenState.Content)
    val state: LoginScreenState by viewModel.states.collectAsState()
    when(state){
        LoginScreenState.Loading -> {
            println("get STATE: Loading")
            progressBar()
        }
        LoginScreenState.Content ->{
            println("get STATE: Content")
        }
        else -> {}
    }
}


@Composable
fun loginScreenUI(viewModel: LoginViewModel) {
    appbar()
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        val username = TextFieldCustom(hint = "Username", false)
        val password = TextFieldCustom(hint = "Password", true)

        Button(
            onClick = {
                println("send EVENT: Click")
                viewModel.send(LoginScreenEvent.OnLoginClick(username, password))},
            Modifier.padding(10.dp)
        ) {
            Text(text = "Login")
        }

    }

}
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: Repository
): ViewModel() {

   var _states = MutableStateFlow<LoginScreenState>(Loading)
    val states: StateFlow<LoginScreenState> = _states

    var _actions = SingleLiveEvent<LoginScreenAction>()
    val actions: LiveData<LoginScreenAction> = _actions

    fun send(event: LoginScreenEvent){
        when (event) {
            is OnLoginClick -> {
                println("get EVENT: OnLoginClick")
                checkCredentials(event.username, event.password)
            }
            Default -> {
                println("set ACTION: Default")
                _actions.value = LoginScreenAction.Default
            }
        }
    }

    private fun checkCredentials(username: String, password: String) {
            _states.value = LoginScreenState.Content
            println("set STATE: Content")
            println("Username: $username Password: $password")
            _actions.value = LoginScreenAction.NavigateToHome
            println("set ACTION: NavigateToHome")
    }
}
```

Comment: Bad Solution but work it: I've deleted action. Now everything is handled only with state. Is logically wrong. if someone has a better solution, let me know ;)

Comment: Personally i think your architecture has a bad implementation because the UI is doing logic with the data received from the viewmodel.  To avoid this, create the necessary livedata, for example LoginScreenState.ContentLoginScreenState.Loading - > isLoadingLiveData(boolean), LoginScreenState.Content -> contentLiveData(yourContentData) and LoginScreenAction.NavigateToHome -> navigateHomeLiveData or navigateLiveData(idNavigation)